# jQuery loop without each and callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I wish to loop throw jQuery collection without `each` and callback call.

I have following code

```
var found1 = false;
$('#Root div.ListItem').each(function( index, d1 ) { 
    if (group == d1.text()){ found1 = true; }
} );

if(found1){
    return;
}
```

Once `found1` is set true Next time it is always true. I would like to know how to loop without `each` and callback like

```
for(var id in $('#Root div.ListItem')) { ... }
```

**UPDATE**

I am not wondering how to break loop.
I do not wish to pass callback in `each`

If I pass jQuery object in loop then I get to many keys.

http://jsfiddle.net/LwTGU/

In that example there might be 1 key for one child element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your attempt to use a `for-in` statement in your fiddle is actually iterating over all of the properties in the `jQuery` array-like object:

```
for (var id in $('#Root div.ListItem')) {
    // id is the name of the property
}
```

You don't want this; you need to iterate over the *elements in* the array-like object:

```
for (var id in $('#root span').toArray()) { // convert to native array
    // id is now an element found by the selector
    $('<div />', {text: $(id).text()}).appendTo($('#out'));
}
```

[You'll see in the above](http://jsfiddle.net/LwTGU/1/) that the output is what you were expecting.

So, back to your original question. It sounds like you just need to break out of your loop once you've found a match. In case you're wondering how to break out of a jQuery `each` loop, simply `return false;` after you set `found1 = true;`. You shouldn't be afraid to pass in a callback; that callback is just executed for each element in your selector in a regular old for-loop "under-the-hood."

If you really want to write the `for-each` structure yourself, then something like this would be sufficient:

```
var found1 = false;
var items = $('#Root div.ListItem').toArray(); // an array of DOM elements
for (var i = 0, j = items.length; i < j; i++) {
    // You can access the DOM elements in the array by index, but you'll
    // have to rewrap them in a jQuery object to be able to call .text()
    if (group == $(items[i]).text()) {
        found1 = true; 
        break; // no need to keep iterating once a match is found
    }
}
```

A shorter but slower way to do this might be to use `$.grep` and check if it found anything:

```
var found1 = $.grep($('#Root div.ListItem'), function() {
    return group == $(this).text();
}).length > 0;
```

I wouldn't recommend the latter unless the selector is only returning a handful of elements (e.g. < 50).

Comment: Does not look nicely-magically like jQuery code often does. But I spent some time googling and I think it is best code I can get. Thank You.

Comment: @Max: I just saw the edit to your question with the fiddle example. I've added some additional information to my answer regarding your example and a revision of your fiddle to check out.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to stop processing when you meet some condition. You can do that with `each` by returning `false` when the condition is met:

```
var found1 = false;
$('#Root div.ListItem').each(function(index, d1) { 
    if (group == d1.text()) { 
        found1 = true; 
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can also iterate over the return value of `$('#Root div.ListItem')` like it's any other array (if you insist on not using `each`).

Answer (score 3):

As I do not have the necessary reputation (50), I was not able to comment on the accepted answer.  However, I do not believe that the following code will work as expected:

```
for (var id in $('#root span').toArray()) { // convert to native array
    // id is now an element found by the selector
    $('<div />', {text: $(id).text()}).appendTo($('#out'));
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, "id" would be an integer representing the iterated array index, not the actual array element.  If so, $(id) would not point to a valid jquery object.  Instead, wouldn't it need to be something like this?

```
for (var id in $('#root span').toArray()) { // convert to native array
    // id is now an element found by the selector
    $('<div />', {text: $($('#root span')[id]).text()}).appendTo($('#out'));
}
```